# Meaning of "shouldn't see one woman": singular or multiple

Tags: meaning-in-context

In this example (no pun intended, of course):

> I shouldn't see one woman on Twitter today being that it's National Sandwich Day.

Does it mean that I'm not likely to see **any** or just **one** woman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you're not likely to see **any** woman on Twitter.

Technically it *could* mean that you're not likely to see *only one* woman on Twitter, but I think the tongue-in-cheek context favors the first meaning.

Comment: Right, but I don't think it's ambiguous at all. Equate with "I shouldn't see a single woman". If you meant "only one woman", or "one woman in particular", you would just say so.

Comment: @Jon Well, yes, you would hope one would say so, and one usually does. I don't think it is ambiguous either. Ambiguity comes from *not* being able to tell the meaning from the context.

My point is that structurally/technically/syntactically, it could also mean ony one woman.

I guess I was being ambiguous. :-)